# Lightning aura If is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, aura-if

I am trying to render 2 text according to change in button Menu select. I am able to get the value of the selected menu but the auro:if condition is not getting reRender properly. My code below

```
<aura:component >    
<aura:attribute name="selectedVal" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<lightning:buttonMenu value="{!selectedVal}" class="slds-dropdown-trigger " alternativeText="Settings" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect}">
    <lightning:menuItem label="Panal 1" value="true" />
    <lightning:menuItem label="Panal 2" value="false"/>
</lightning:buttonMenu>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


{!v.selectedVal}<br/>
{!v.selectedVal == true}<br/>
{!v.selectedVal == false}
    <aura:If istrue="{!v.selectedVal}">
        <p aura:id="p1" >p1</p>            
    </aura:If >

    <aura:if istrue="{!!v.selectedVal}">
            testing
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
handleMenuSelect : function(component, event, helper) {
    var selectedMenuItemValue = event.getParam("value");
    var selected = selectedMenuItemValue;
     console.log(selectedMenuItemValue);
    component.set("v.selectedVal", selectedMenuItemValue);        
} })
```

My text is not getting renderd when the selected value is changed. i used if and else auro:set condition even if it is not working. Do anyone have any idea.

[image]

Above is the screenshot of what i am getting after selecting panel 1 from button option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually because "true" and "false" are rendering as String values, even though your attribute is a Boolean. I'm not sure *why* Lightning allows this, but the easiest fix is to use the true and false global providers:

```
    <lightning:menuItem label="Panal 1" value="{!true}" />
    <lightning:menuItem label="Panal 2" value="{!false}"/>
```

Or, compare as strings:

```
{!v.selectedVal}<br/>
{!v.selectedVal == 'true'}<br/>
{!v.selectedVal == 'false'}
```

Also, please be aware that Lightning is case sensitive, and may have undesirable side effects if you ignore it. aura:if won't work if you use `istrue`, but will work if you use `isTrue`. Mind your capitalization.

```
<!-- does not render -->
<aura:if istrue="{!!v.selectedVal}">
    testing
</aura:if>
<!-- works just fine -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.selectedVal}">
    testing
</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is at lightning:buttonmenu  <s>`value="{!selectedVal}"`</s> ,you must append with using value provider `v` ( This value provider enables you to access the value of a component’s attribute in the component’s markup) eg:

`value="{!v.selectedVal}"` refer this for more details [Value Providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm)

and Lightning is case sensitive use `isTrue` not <s>`istrue`</s>

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedVal}">
    <p aura:id="p1" >p1</p>            
</aura:if >

<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.selectedVal}">
        testing
</aura:if>
<lightning:buttonMenu value="{!v.selectedVal}" class="slds-dropdown-trigger " alternativeText="Settings" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect}">
```

Comment: I made the change as mentioned in answer. But still not able to reRender my auro:if tag

Comment: @Anu I made changes on answer look it.

Comment: Thanks I was not sure about lightning is case sensitive. Thanks